# Can we get a set of quick links to other SE sites that work like [tour]?

Tags: feature-request

It would be handy to have quick links to other sites when you want to suggest that the question might be better handled there. I know a lot of the abbreviations from the hot questions ribbon, but digging out a link when I need one is a pain. Please use the same abbreviations used in the ribbon.

By quick links, I mean just using the square brackets to trigger the link without having to use parentheses and the address.

Comment: Hmm, do we not have a [formatting sandbox](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the feature you want already exists, at least for comments ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290413/323179)'s a feature request to bring this syntax to posts too). According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/323179):

> - `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`/`[meta.se]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com), the [Stack Exchange portal](https://stackexchange.com/)). Link text is the site name.
> - `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for Ask Ubuntu, and `[mathoverflow.se]` for Math Overflow.
>
>   To link to a site-specific Meta site, use: `[sitename.meta.se]` or `[meta.sitename.se]`.

Using the HNQ site ballon letters would be problematic for several reasons: most graduated sites don't have letters in their icons (e.g. [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)), some sites have the same letter(s) used (e.g. [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/) and [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/)), and the icons don't always use alphanumeric characters (e.g. [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) and [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/)).

If that doesn't work for you, you can try [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/6650).

Comment: Support is thin, apparently. I can't get any that I'm interested in to work.

Comment: @PhilSweet What sites?

Comment: I tried Interpersonal.se and Engineering.se every which way I could think of.

Comment: Test: [ell.se] vs [interpersonal.se] vs [engineering.se].

Comment: @PhilSweet They work! I coded them as `[ell.se]`, `[interpersonal.se]` and `[engineering.se]`.

Comment: weird, see my test in the [sandbox](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here) [ell.se]

Comment: Okay, weirder still, works here, but not in the test area :(

Comment: @PhilSweet Magic links only work in comments.

Comment: `[tour] [help] [help/on-topic]` [tour] [help] [help/on-topic]